# Slow ListPlot with PlotMarkers

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am doing this:

```
ClearAll[matrix];
matrix[p_,q_,nu_:0]:=Module[{sigma},
 sigma=p/q;
 N@SparseArray[
  {{m_,m_}\[Rule]2Cos[2\[Pi]*m*p/q+nu],{i_,j_}/;
   Abs[i-j]\[Equal]1\[Rule]1},{q,q}]]

ClearAll[attachsigma]
attachsigma[sigma_,lst_]:={sigma,#}&/@lst
```

and then execute

```
fracs = Table[p/q, {q, 2, 30}, {p, 2, q}] // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates;
pq = {Numerator@#, Denominator@#} & /@ fracs;
(ens = Eigenvalues[#] & /@ 
Normal /@ (matrix[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ pq);) // Timing
pts = Flatten[#, 1] &@MapThread[attachsigma, {fracs, ens}];
```

and finally I plot the points as follows (here is the real point of the question):

```
plot = ListPlot[pts,
 PlotMarkers \[Rule] Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], Point[{0, 0}]}]]
```

[image: Hofstadter]

Calculating all the points takes around around 2.6s on my machine, but the plot takes around 25s. If, on the other hand, I plot it like this

```
ListPlot[pts]
```

[image: Hofstadter]

then it is almost instantaneous, as it should (it's just 5256 points). So, it seems `PlotMarkers` slows things down immensely.

Could anybody 
a) explain why (this much I vaguely understand, in analogy with what happens to `Sort` if you give it custom ordering function) and, more importantly, 
b) explain how to avoid this slowdown? I am trying to create plots with quite a bit more points than this so they're really slow; in addition, I am creating lots of them (a movie actually).

One solution would be to not plot all of them, but as I vary parameters it becomes nontrivial to find out which I should include and which not (this would of course work if I only needed this one frame). So, I'd like to speed up the plot creation without removing points.

EDIT: Answered after hints from Sjoerd:

```
ListPlot[pts] /. Point[List[x___]] \[RuleDelayed] {PointSize[Tiny], Point[List[x]]}
```

produces the right thing instantaneously. This simply replaces the `Points` inside the `Graphics` structure by smaller points by hand.

Now one can increase the upper limit in the table in `fracs = Table[p/q, {q, 2, 30}, {p, 2, q}] // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates` to 80 or so to get many more points (this thing is the Hofstadter butterfly, and it's a fractal):

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`PlotMarkers` is meant for data plots that contain relatively few points. It is very useful in plots in which you use the markers to identify various conditions. Each individual marker is an `Inset` as follows:

```
Inset[Graphics[List[Hue[0.67`,0.6,0.6`],PointSize[Tiny],Point[List[0, 0]]]],10512].
```

You can imagine this takes up some time and  memory.

I also found what seems to be a **bug**. The plot with `PlotMarkers` is structured as `GraphicsComplex[pointlist,graphicsinstructions]`. This point list seems to contain the points in the plot twice!

```
In[69]:= pts // Length

Out[69]= 5256

In[66]:= plot[[1, 1]] // Length

Out[66]= 10512

In[64]:= Union[plot[[1, 1]]] == Union[pts]

Out[64]= True

In[68]:= Tally[plot[[1, 1]]][[All, 2]] // Mean (*the average number each point occurs*)

Out[68]= 2
```

Comment: Thanks. You're right, `FullForm` shows that this is indeed how they are represented. Do you have any suggestions on how to speed things up nevertheless? For instance, `ListPlot[pts] /. Point[List[x___]] :> smth` could work if I could pick the right `smth`, but graphics in mma are not my thing...

Comment: @acl Saw your edit. Point resolved quickly. Did you see my last edit?

Comment: yes, I was experimenting just now and it seems you're right. Funny

Comment: So now it's just as fast as `ListPlot` generally is. Great.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I prefer `Graphics` to `ListPlot`, especially when the number of points is large.

```
Graphics[{Hue[{2/3, 1, 1, .5}], AbsolutePointSize[1.5], Point@pts}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-4, 4}}, Axes -> False, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

gives, for example:

[image]

```
Length@pts
```

102969

Comment: thanks. This takes the same time as `ListPlot` without the `PlotMarkers`, which makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the solution you appended to your question can be simplified:

```
ListPlot[pts] /. x_Point :> {PointSize[Tiny], x}
```

---

I voted for both prior answers, but I agree with TomD on the direct use of `Graphics`.

Comment: You're right, doing it all at once is less keystrokes. And perhaps the use of `Graphics` is indeed better: I was hoping to reduce effort by using `ListPlot` (which I clearly didn't in the end...)